# How can I switch off PlotRangeClipping from one side of the plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to make `PlotRangeClipping -> True` on each side of the plot (see code below) except the top side must be `PlotRangeClipping -> Flase`, is that possible?

```
Plot[{x, -x}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, 
 Frame -> True,PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -1.8}}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> 80]
```

[image]

**Update**

The problem is that I would like to place the legend at a specific position so that I used

```
Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
        LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, -1.8}}]
```

of course, the problem would be solved if I replace `{{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, -1.8}}` by `Above` ( as shown in the answer by @Bob Hanlon) but this will not help me to place the legend at the desired position.

Comment: add the option `RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &)`?

Comment: may please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the option `RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &)` gives the desired result:

```
Plot[{x, -x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -1.8}}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> 80, 
 RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Just one more question please, can I use it with `ListLinePlot`? e.g. `data = Table[{x, x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}];` `ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -1.8}}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> 80, RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &)]`.is not working

Comment: @valarmorghulis, you can use `ListLinePlot[Select[-1 <= #[[1]] <= 0 &]@data,...]` (similarly for `ListPlot`).

Comment: Thanks @klgr, but it did not work when I use this type of data `data=Transpose[Table[{x, Sign[i] x^2 + i}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}, {i, -5, 5, 1}]]`. i tried this `ListLinePlot[Select[-2 <= #[[1]] <= 2 &]@Transpose[data], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True]`

Comment: try `data = Transpose[Table[{x, Sign[i] x^2 + i}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}, {i, -5, 5, 
    1}]]; ListLinePlot[Map[Select[-2 <= #[[1]] <= 2 &]]@data, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an [`XY problem`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Apparently, you want to display the legend above the plot. The issue is not [`PlotRangeClipping`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html). Use [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html)

```
Plot[{x, -x}, {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"Y1", "Y2"}, Above]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or you can control the [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html)

```
Plot[{x, -x}, {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Y1", "Y2"}, Above],
 ImagePadding -> {{80, 80}, {80, 5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @bob Hanlon, I am aware of the solution you provided, but for some reason I need to assign ImagePadding to be 80 in my plot.

Comment: Recommend that you provide a more complete description of the desired end result.

Comment: I would like to place the legends at specific position above the plot..Using Above places the legend randomly on the top of the plot which is not desired.